# Why do I have to use variance and not mean value to calculate noise?

Tags: noise

Why, when I have to calculate some types of noise (for example shot noise and others which are in the denominator of SNR ratio) or attenuation from turbulence, I have to use variance of the of the density probability and not the mean value? In all of the formulas they use  variance (the second moment) and this is not clear for me.

Comment: Noise is almost universally assumed to be zero-mean. Think about a noise signal in the form of a voltage: a nonzero mean equates to a nonzero DC voltage component. You could then lowpass filter it to remove all but the DC and use that voltage as a power source! That's not likely to be true for real passive noise sources.

Answer (score 2):

Typically the first moment (mean) is zero and therefore contains (relatively) no information. The most obvious thing then, to distinguish different levels of noise, is to look at the variance.

And if the variance happens to be zero, then surely there is no noise at all.